# How to avoid the pop-up callout in the toolbar in ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, toolbar

I try to find a way to avoid from seen the pop up callout any time i stand on each of the toolbar functions.I mean this such of callout for example:

[image]

I try to change the default in the file "AdvancedArcMapSettings", but i didn't found any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Showing tooltips on toolbars](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/customizing-the-ui/showing-tooltips-on-toolbars.htm) for ArcGIS 10.3:

> 1. Click the **Customize** menu and click **Customize Mode**.
> 2. Click the **Options** tab.
> 3. Check **Show Tooltips on toolbars** to display Tooltips for the buttons on a toolbar.
> 4. Click **Close**.

Instead of checking it, try unchecking it.